# Indexer / Search Engine to crawl all files in website directory

Tags: php, html, search, indexing, web-crawler

I'm looking for a web-based version of the app below:

http://www.fileseek.ca/

Any ideas on where I could find/install something like this? My objective is to be make it easier for my developers to search for and find specific terms inside PHP/HTML/CSS/etc. files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out 
[OpenGrok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGrok). We are very happy with it.
If you want to play around, write some code in Java, and customize, you can try playing with 
[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)